# If $M_c$ is finitely generated, then it is a principal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

The following question is a part of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447559/m-a-f-in-c0-1-fa-0-for-a-in-0-1-is-m-a-finitely-gene?rq=1) problem.

Let $R = \{ f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} \; | \; f \text{ is a continuous map} \}$ be the ring of continuous functions. We define $M_c = \{ f \in R \; | \; f(c)=0 \}$. It is very easy to prove that $M_c$ is a maximal ideal. The final result we want to prove is:

> $M_c$ is not a finitely generated ideal.

One of the claims which I saw while reading from [here](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~kesmith/593hmwk2-2014-solutions.pdf) is the following:

> If $M_c$ is finitely generated, then it is a principal ideal.

(Later they use this result that since $M_c$ is not a principal ideal, and hence $M_c$ is not finitely generated.)

*Proof.* Assume that $M_c = \left<f_1,\dots,f_n\right>$. The function $f_{1}^{1/3}$ is also in $M_c$ so write it as $\sum_{i=1}^n g_if_i$ for some $g_i \in R$. Cubing both side, we have:
$f_1 = \sum h_if_i$ where, in particular, $h_1$ vanishes at $c$ (gathering up coefficients of $f_1$ in $(\sum g_if_i)^3$; we see the coefficient $h_i$ is in the ideal $<f_1, \dots, f_n>^2$).

So, $(1 − h_1)f_1 \in  <f_1, \dots, f_n>$. Since $1 − h_1$ does not vanish at $c$, we can find an interval $B = [a, b]$ containing $c$ where it also doesn’t vanish.

Here is what I don't understand:

Doubt: In the ring $S$ of continuous functions on $B, \; 1 − h_1$ is a unit, hence on this ring $S$, the ideal $M_c$ is generated by $<f_2|_{B}, \dots, f_n|_{B}>$. 
How does this follow?

Comment: Perhaps some additional precision would be helpful here.  It is not the case that every finitely generated ideal is principal.  It depends on the ring that you're working in.  In the linked question, it appears (at first glance) that the ring is $C[0,1]$.  In general, making this question more self-contained would be advantageous.  Perhaps by defining $M_c$.